# Ceiling effect in mediation AND/OR moderation

Tags: regression

I have a variable (Y) with a mean that is probably too high. (and large prop of participants scoring the maximum score)

My hypothesis was that X-Y is stronger at high (vs. low) levels of the moderator M, 
but now I see that the interaction comes out to be significant but in a way that X-Y assocation is stronger at lower, rather than higher, levels of M.
I think this is because of the ceiling effect (i.e., it was not possible that X-Y at high levels of M can be higher than one at low levels of M because there was no way Y could go further up).

But I was wondering if it makes sense to use this variable as a mediator.
I have another hypothesis using this variable as a mediator and the indirect effect does come out to be significant, and in a predicted way.
So I was wondering if it is more of a problem when such a variable is used as a outcome variable in a moderation than as a mediator...

On the one hand, this does not make sense because after all mediation IS a regression analysis and uses this variable as a DV in some way, 
but on the other hand, looking at how its association with another variable varies by the level of the third variable (DV in a moderation) does look different from just looking at it as a mediator...

I would really appreciate any help!!!